# spring mvc prevent direct access a method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, data-access

I just started learning spring mvc 3. I found a small problem where my controller would handle a post request (registration form). but if type the mapping value (bla3/save.html) in address bar, it will execute the method which it shouldn't. That's why I need a solution for this, if someone type the address directly, it should redirect to other pages instead trying to add new user.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST) //save new user
public ModelAndView saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result){
    userService.addUser(user);  
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/users.html");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the URL directly in the address bar it would be a GET request for which you can handle a different behaviour e.g. GET is prohibited for this URL or render the blank form for the User on the submission of which the POST method will be called upon.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result){
    userService.addUser(user);  

}
```

Comment: ok so basically all I have to do is create another method to handle GET request. I'll try it tomorrow since the project is in my office pc.

Comment: yes .. just have a controller method to act on the HTTP GET request

Answer (score 1):

Add this method in your controller class.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "bla3/save", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result){
    userService.addUser(user);  
...
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/users.html");
}
```

If type the mapping value (bla3/save.html) in address bar. This method will execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the method only be executed only when there are specific headers like below code.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers="X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest")
```

In this case the method is only be executed when it is an jquery ajax request (jQuery automatically adds the header)

Of course it is just kind of Poka-yoke